# Should implementations of java.util.Comparator.compare(T o1, T o2) be thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, comparator

Or should I only care when used in parallel implementations like `java.util.Arrays.parallelSort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> cmp)` ?

Comment: Why do you think it may need to be thread safe? The comparison function shouldn't modify anything anyway. When the array is being sorted, I can't imagine what kind of result you are expecting if you allow the data to be modified.

Comment: @nhahtdh Like I said in the question. Maybe there is non thread safe state in the class like a SimpleDateFormat and the compare method is being called by two threads from a parallel sorter.

Answer (score 5):

The comparison method is by its nature a pure function evaluated against objects which may be considered immutable at least during the sorting operation. Mutating the objects during sorting would break the essential assumption of any sorting algorithm, which is that the order imposed by the `Comparator` is stable throughout the operation.

The above implies that, although the comparator must be thread-safe when used in a parallel sort, it is usually a given with no special effort. On the flip side, you do need to make sure it doesn't contain thread-unsafe code for one reason or another, such as using a thread-unsafe collaborator instance shared across all invocations of `compare()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to make things thread-safe. In contrast to other answers, IMO it could be non-thread-safe, for example, when a `Comparator` uses an object like `SimpleDateFormat` as a member variable which would not be thread-safe.

Since someone using a comparator would not expect to have to deal with concurrency, it is certainly a good idea to make it thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Although in most cases comparator is either thread-safe by design or used in single thread, there are also cases when comparator can be used concurrently. In parallel sort, as you mentioned, or in concurrent collections, as `ConcurrentSkipListMap`.

In these cases, obviously, comparator must be thread safe or synchronized.